# vim colorschemes not displaying properly

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm running vim in the default Mac terminal and I'm trying to change the color scheme to one of the included color schemes, but none of them seem to be displaying properly.

For example, if I type :colorscheme blue, the colors change but there is a white border around the background.

[image]

Additionally, if I type :colorscheme desert, which is the color scheme I want to use, the syntax highlighting changes, but the background color does not.

[image]

Note that the desert color scheme is ostensibly supposed to look like this:
[image]

Why are these color schemes not displaying properly, and is there a way to fix them? Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is that if you use gvim (or macvim on a mac), your colorschemes will probably work fine. The longer answer is that vim in a terminal uses the colors available in that terminal. There are settings concerning whether your terminal uses 16 or 256 or 16bit color, and there are settings concerning whether vim knows your terminal can use many colors. One thing that people sometimes do is change their terminal colorscheme, which as a byproduct changes vim's colorscheme.

Comment: Tip for others like me who found some syntax highlighting horribly difficult to read in vim in gitbash/mintty.  You can switch the mintty theme via the Options menu (click top left corner or press ALT+SPACE then choose Options. Under the Looks section you can select a different theme. For me, rosipov worked well with the python code I am trying to edit. Hth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim's `set background={light|dark}` is *not* designed to change your background color, it is designed to work with your existing background color and give you colors that show up on that background.

Some colorschemes have multiple options to try and reproduce what the designers wanted in a variety of settings. For example, the colorscheme I am using has a base section with all the color settings followed by a 256 color specific section:

```
....
hi LineNr          guifg=#465457 guibg=#232526
if &t_Co > 255
    hi Normal       ctermfg=252 " ctermbg=232
    hi CursorLine               ctermbg=234   cterm=none
    ...
```

which sets all the colors based on having a 256 color terminal, so that way people with 256 color terminals can still get close to what the colorscheme author intended, since a 256 color terminal cannot draw RRGGBB colors.

Likewise, colorschemes can respect `background` and change the colors they are using to be visible on that background color (so dark terminals don't have comments as dark blue, for example).

Lastly, `vim` only attempts to draw the background where it can draw characters, i.e., only the printable area of the screen. If your terminal width is, for instance, between 64 and 65 `COLUMNS` wide, then vim can only draw 64 characters, and there will be some space around the edges where vim doesn't try to draw, leaving the terminal's default background.

On Mac's Terminal.app, the easiest way to change your background color is to go to Preferences -> Profiles and either choose a default theme or edit the **Background** "Colors & Effects" section to be what you want.